# How to update the value of a column in my table when the current tab close or navigate to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-5

I have a page  and I named it to **mypage.php**. I have a table **MyTable** with a column **STATUS**. I want to update the status to **T** when the user enters to the page and change to **F** when the user leaves or close from the page.
I tried with ***onbeforeunload*** with JS. Help me any way.

Comment: can we please see what youve tried so far? It'll help us to understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
window.onunload=function(){
 /......when user closes..../
}
window.onload=function(){
/....when user enters page.../}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try the "onfocusout" or "blur" event if you want to update it when the user goes on another tab and not only when he close your tab. Put the onfocusout on the body tag and it will fire when the user will exit your tab, by switching to another tab or by closing yours.